# Perl - moving files from DIR1 to DIR2

Tags: perl, cwd

I am trying to move files from DIR1 to DIR2 using Perl script.
My code compiles but unfortunately is not working properly.
Thanks in advance for suggestions

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use File::Copy;
use Cwd 'abs_path';

if ( @ARGV != 2 ) {
    die "Script takes two parameters: dir1 dir2";
}

if ( -d $ARGV[0] && -d $ARGV[1]  )
{
    opendir my $DIR, $ARGV[0] or die "Read error: $!";

    while(my $file = readdir $DIR ) 
    {
        next if ($file eq "." or $file eq "..");

            my $filepath = abs_path($file);
            print "$filepath\n";

            move $filepath, $ARGV[1];
    }
    closedir $DIR;
}
else
{
    print "Both arguments must be directories!\n";
}
```

Script prints all files in DIR1 but move fails.

Comment: This question is both, too specific (i.e. will probably never help anyone else) and not well researched (some simple print-debugging or debugger session would have revealed the mistake). Please leave yourself a little more time to research and phrase your question before posting in the future. Thank you!

Comment: `abs_path` doesn't do what you think it does.  It just looks at the argument you gave it, and returns what an absolute path would be if that argument represented a relative path.  It does **not** search your file system to figure out where that file is and return the actual absolute path to that file.  You need to supply the directory yourself, which is contained in `$ARGV[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readdir` returns only the filenames in the given directory. Thus to get an absolute filepath you need to prepend $ARGV[0].
See the [perldoc for readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) for detailed information.

Comment: Or don't, and just use `glob` instead.